# Does OOP apply to Xcode storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, subclass, scene

I'm working on a flash card app. The user picks the question and answer categories separately. Some question categories are textual ("What is the capital of Brazil?", others are images ("This is the national flag of what country?").

The questions in a given round will either be always text or always images. Therefore, I have two separate scenes in my storyboards, one for each option.

90% of the scenes are the same: Question counter, Correct and Incorrect answers counters, 4 `UIButton`s for multiple choice answers, `UIButton` to return to main menu. Similarly, 90% of the code for each `UIViewController` subclass is also the same and so I will abstract it to a superclass.

But...can the same be done for the *visual* elements? Like a PowerPoint presentation that has the same header on each page.

I'd love to have two "layers" on my scenes....the first layer presents the common elements and is controlled by a single parent VC, the second layer presents the elements specific to each scene and is controlled by the corresponding VC.

Am I dreaming? Or is there something I haven't yet learned or figured out?

While writing this, I'm thinking that custom views might be the solution, but I can't get my head around it. Even with a custom view, I'd still have to make the connections to the common elements each time, won't I?

Any thoughts, hints, suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: hey @Zonker.in.Geneva, got any news on the issue? do you need more explanation? :)

Comment: Hi. Sorry. Yes, what you said really helped. I don't think I understood it fully, but enough to make some progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is no problem at all! You can create a superclass, let's call it `SuperVC` (which itself is a subclass of `UIViewController`), add `IBOutlets` to it, then create subclasses of `SuperVC`, let's call them `SubVC1` and `SubVC2`, and also create `IBOutlets` in those. Then, in your Storyboard you can connect the appropriate elements to all these `IBOutlets`, only make sure that you open the correct file in the *Assistant Editor* to do so (logically, if you connect `IBOutlets` from `SuperVC` you need to have `SuperVC` open in the *Asisstant Editor*, likewise for `SubVC1` and `SubVC2`).

By the way, you can do this with custom `UIViews` as well. Here again, you also have the option whether you want to create these in Interface Builder or in code... so really, there are no technical limitations on this issue :)

Comment: When you say I can create `IBOutlets`, do you mean by Control-dragging? Or by just typing in the correct @property code? And then connecting later?

I *feel* like I need a superclass scene, but I think you're saying I don't.

(sorry for the delay, I was walking the dog!)

Comment: haha no problem, dogs need walks ;) you can actually do both, you can type out the `IBOutlet` and connect it later on, but you can also create it using drag&drop... this really doesn't make a difference. by the way, I didn't mean to say that you don't need a superclass scene, I think this would indeed be very appropriate for your scenario

Comment: ummm, now i have more questions...

if I can control-drag these `IBOutlets` from `SuperVC`, where do I drag them *to*? You said: create `SuperVC`, add `IBOutlets` to it, ... in Storyboard connect the appropriate elements"

But....what's the difference between "add `IBOutlets`" and "connect the appropriate elements?

I'm confused. Sadly, too easily.

Comment: you drag them to your storyboard scene... make sure that you set the class of the scene appropriately to `SuperVC` or `SubVC`, then Xcode allows you to perform these drag&drop actions

Comment: "adding IBOutlets" and "connecting the elements" both refer to connecting storyboard elements with your code. not sure if you know this, but you can just go and type your `IBOutlets` and then connect them afterwards instead of creating them _by_ dragging and dropping

Comment: Hmmmm. Maybe I just need to try it out, but I'm really confused now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78514/discussion-between-nburk-and-zonker-in-geneva).

Comment: sorry I didnt mean to confuse you :D
basically it's pretty straightforward. maybe indeed the best for you would be to start and come back to SO once you really got stuck on a specific issue. for now, just now that creating this superclass scene is absolutely possible and does seem appropriate for your situation.